# Best way to define developer-dependent variables for .Net IIS App

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, environment-variables

I have an .Net application shared by multiple developers. Some developers want a different configuration in `Application_Start()`, but we all share the same codebase.

What is the best way to define a custom variable that different devs can change?

My current approach is:

```
string value = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(UserEnvironmentalVariableName, EnvironmentVariableTarget.User);
```

but the application is not run under the user account on IIS, so this does not work.

Comment: nconfig is a plugin that lets you override web.config settings, on different computers. You name it based on the machine name, so each person would have their own personal one. Sounds exactly what you're looking for. (I believe it is available via nuget)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ideas:

1) How about using normal AppSettings and store in your application's web.config all the ones that are standard to everyone.
Then anyone can store in their root web.config (like \Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\web.config) any other variables they want. As long as "UserEnvironmentalVariableName" is not in your application's web.config then it will just inherit whatever is in the machine's root web.config.

2) Another option which would play really nice with your existing code is if the developers are using Windows 10 is that you can set the Environment Variables now at the application Pool level

```
appcmd.exe set config  -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+"[name='DefaultAppPool'].environmentVariables.[name='myPersonalVariable',value='some value']" /commit:apphost
```

Or just edit applicationHost.config and add them there like below:

```
    <applicationPools>
        <add name="DefaultAppPool" managedRuntimeVersion="v4.0">
            <environmentVariables>
                <add name="myPersonalVariable" value="some value" />
            </environmentVariables>
        </add>
    </applicationPools>
```

3) another one is use config transformations in Visual Studio: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318.aspx

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately we're not all on Windows 10, but that is great to know. I went with the first option as it seemed the most straightforward to me.